# String List doesnt save values and keeps being empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, list, initialization

I have this class:

```
 public class Section
{
    [Key]
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public string Titre { get; set; }
    public virtual List<String> Tag { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ressource> Ressources { get; set; }
    public Section() { this.Tag=new List<string>(); }
}
```

In a createsection view, I send a string containing the tags separated by spaces or other characters to the controller and I split this string into a list like this:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public ActionResult CreerSection(Section section, string tags)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //section.Id = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };

            section.Tag = tags.Split(delimiterChars).ToList();
            _db.Entry(section).State = EntityState.Added;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index" );
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I put a breaking point next to the "section.Tag =" line, and I noticed that the Tag list contains now all the tags (ie: "tag1" "tag2" "tag3") sent from the createview. Perfect so far...

Then in a different view, the Section view, when I want to show all the section tags, the tag list is equal to 0 and doesnt contain the values "tag1" "tag2" and "tag3" Why?

```
@model Mocodis.Models.Section
@foreach (string s in Model.Tag)
{
    <p>@s</p>
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would rather call the dbSet.add method when the object is new and the dbSet.attach method when the object already exists. Like this

```
_dbset.Add(entity); //object is new (create)
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Or

```
_dbset.Attach(entity); //object already exists in the dbset (update/modify)
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I suppose you are using EF. Btw, why are you using 'virtual List Tag'. How is this saved to the database? In a separate table? Did you already check if the date was added to the table?

Kr

Comment: Actually it wasnt saved to the database, and I thought that there is no need to be... but I think it didnt work out because the list tag isnt associated with the section and everytime when I call the list, I get a new one that's why it's always empty... 
To fix it, I integrated the tags in the database as a string (containing all the tags separated by spaces) attribute to the Section table. When I want to get the list of tags, I use a function to split the string and put the tags into a list. Yes I'm using EF. Thank you

Comment: Indeed, to persist the tags as a string, it is needed to save them in the database. Whenever you recall your object, you will have access to the saved data.